# 0's are truncate while write in to an csv using php function

Tags: php, csv

I have try to write data to csv using the php function.

But the 0's are truncate while write in to an csv.

```
$data = array ( 'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd', '000123,456,789','"aaa","bbb"');

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');

foreach($data as $line)
{
  $val = explode(",",$line);
  fputcsv($fp, $val);
} 

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I think your application removes them, not your code. Excel for instance, attempts to recognize data types and parse them the way it suits best.

Comment: It might help to treat the numbers as strings: '"000123","456","789"'

Comment: I try this '"000123","456","789"', but the Quotes are displayed in the excel cell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are trying to open csv in excel or open office, it will truncate leading zeros.
 when u construct the string with "\t" before zero to avoid 0 truncation

Answer (score 2):

I think Excel has treated it as a number and omitted the 0.

You may try to do this:

```
fputcsv ($fp, "='".$val."'");
```

See if it works

Comment: This is susceptible to errors if the value contains quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could find that it's Excel, etc that's eating the 0 characters (you can test this out by opening the csv file in notepad (or whatever your favourite text editor is) and seeing if they're there.

If that's not the case then try using the following line:

```
fputcsv($fp, (string) $val);
```

Just in case the variable is somehow being cast to an integer somewhere.